# Who is subscriber of PropertyChangedEventHandler

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am very new to WPF MVVM.

After implementing an INotifyPropertyChanged interface, there is one event which gets added:

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

as per my understanding, "PropertyChangedEventHandler" is a delegate, so I want to understand what methods are subscribing to this delegates?

Comment: The typical consumer of the PropertyChanged event is a Binding.

Comment: By binding, you mean UI binding right?. Sorry for such dumb question but just wanted to be clear

Comment: Sure, the WPF Binding class.

Comment: _"I want to understand what methods are subscribing to this delegates?"_ -- I don't understand what you're asking. An event is subscribed to by _any_ code that wants to be notified when the event is raised. In the case of WPF and `PropertyChanged`, WPF wants to know when the property changes, so _its_ method or methods are subscribed to the event. If someone gave you the actual name of a method, what would you do with that information? The method won't even be public...it'll be an implementation detail of WPF. You shouldn't need to know or care what the method is.

Answer (score 1):

INotifyPropertyChanged gives you:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

then you can add an OnPropertyChanged method to process when a property changes:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

So then, when you want to inform that a property has changed, you can call OnPropertyChanged such as from the property's set method itself. In this example, ShowRock is a property and when it changes (via the setter) it lets the world know that it changed:

```
public bool ShowRock
{
    get { return _showRock; }
    set
    {
        _showRock = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ShowRock");
    }
}
```